# Initialize angular application with requests

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application I need to make a couple of request, using `$http`, and store the data in the `$rootScope` before the routes is executed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is the run method:

```
angular.module('yourModule').run(['$rootScope', '$http',
  function($rootScope, $http) {
    $rootScope.foo = 'foo';
  }
]);
```

This is executed before the routing starts.

HOWEVER, it is not good practice to store lots of global data in the $rootScope. It is better to use a service (also possible in the run method) and inject the service in your controllers only when you really need it.

Comment: I've tried that but my request is perfomed async using the $http module. I need to wait until the response is back. I'm using $rootScope to store the current account and current team.